# Loop over a YAML dictionary

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

When looping over a nested YAML structure I am getting the following error:

> [host] (item=script.sh) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": false, "item": "script.sh", "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode object' has no attribute 'ips'"}

Here is the YAML structure:

```yaml
cluster_topology:
  regions:
    ca-west-1:
        ips:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 2.2.2.2
    ca-east-1:
        ips:
          - 3.3.3.3
          - 4.4.4.4
```

Here is the Jinja2 template:

```
{% for region in cluster_topology.regions %}
echo {{ region }}
echo {{ region.ips }}
{% endfor %}
```

I have tried lots of different iterations of the YAML structure, as well as accessing the `ips` field using both dot notation and bracket notation but the same error occurs.

Is anyone able to advise what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To loop over a dictionary, you can either use the [`for key, value in my_dict.items()`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/#for) of Jinja.

Given:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: |-
      {% for region, value in cluster_topology.regions.items() %}
      echo {{ region }}
      echo {{ value.ips }}
      {% endfor %}
  vars:
    cluster_topology:
      regions:
        ca-west-1:
            ips:
              - 1.1.1.1
              - 2.2.2.2
        ca-east-1:
            ips:
              - 3.3.3.3
              - 4.4.4.4
```

Which yields:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: |-
    echo ca-west-1
    echo ['1.1.1.1', '2.2.2.2']
    echo ca-east-1
    echo ['3.3.3.3', '4.4.4.4']
```

Or, you can use the [`dict2items`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/dict2items_filter.html) filter.

This task yielding the same result as the above one:

```yaml
- debug:
    msg: |-
      {% for region in cluster_topology.regions | dict2items %}
      echo {{ region.key }}
      echo {{ region.value.ips }}
      {% endfor %}
  vars:
    cluster_topology:
      regions:
        ca-west-1:
            ips:
              - 1.1.1.1
              - 2.2.2.2
        ca-east-1:
            ips:
              - 3.3.3.3
              - 4.4.4.4
```

Comment: Is there a preferable approach? E.g. 'dict2items' is the way to go due to simplicity and it was introduced specifically for this issue.

Comment: @KevinC the `for` syntax is a Jinja construct, while `dict2items` is an Ansible provided Jinja filter. So, for a case like this I would, personally, prefer the `for` construct as it is more portable and could probably also be more readable for people fluent in Python.